# Azure DataFactory Integrated HDInsight Spark Problem

Tags: apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory

When i use Data Factory, created `HDInsight Spark activity`, there are two options in type(script and jar), when i choose **jar to run**( i use **scala** to develop jar file, it ran **succeeded** by `remote livy submit`) ,it **failed** and log shows:

```
*stdout: 
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.6.5.3009-43/spark2/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/hdp/2.6.5.3009-43/spark_llap/spark-llap-assembly-1.0.0.2.6.5.3009-43.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Error: --py-files given but primary resource is not a Python script
Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output

stderr: 

YARN Diagnostics: 
java.lang.Exception: No YARN application is found with tag livy-batch-4-tpqnpjdw in 120 seconds. Please check your cluster status, it is may be very busy.
org.apache.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp.org$apache$livy$utils$SparkYarnApp$$getAppIdFromTag(SparkYarnApp.scala:182) org.apache.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkYarnApp.scala:239) org.apache.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkYarnApp.scala:236) scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120) org.apache.livy.utils.SparkYarnApp$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkYarnApp.scala:236) org.apache.livy.Utils$$anon$1.run(Utils.scala:97)
*
```

but when i choose script **to run**( using `python` to develop scrits) , it **succeeded**, can anyone solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour in HDInsight Spark Activity.

**Reason:** It's mandatory to specify at least a **Python file** or a **.jar file** while running HDInsight Spark activity.

[image]

From the error message "`Error: --py-files given but primary resource is not a Python script`" clearly says it not a Python script.

**Reference:** [Transform data using Spark activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-spark)

Hope this helps.

Comment: of course, i specified the jar file, what i mean is when i specified the jar file, it run failed, but i specified the python script, it ran succeeded.